# async function in Python, basic example

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Can you help me see what I have understood wrong here please. I have two functions and I would like the second one to run regardless of the status of the first one (whether it is finished or not). Hence I was thinking to make the first function asynchronous. This is what I have done

```
import os
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

async def do_some_iterations():
    for i in range(10):
        print(datetime.now().time())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('... Cool!')


async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task (do_some_iterations())
    await task

def do_something():
    print('something...')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
    do_something()
```

The output is:

```
00:46:00.145024
00:46:01.148533
00:46:02.159751
00:46:03.169868
00:46:04.179915
00:46:05.187242
00:46:06.196356
00:46:07.207614
00:46:08.215997
00:46:09.225066
 Cool!
something...
```

which looks like the traditional way where one function has to finish and then move to the next call.

I was hoping instead to execute `do_something()` before the asynchronous function started generating the print statements (or at lease at the very top of those statements..)

What am I doing wrong please? How I should edit the script?

Comment: You only have one task. Try to add another one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They both need to be part of the event loop the you created. `asyncio.run()` itself is not async, which means it will run until the loop ends. One easy way to do this is to use [`gather()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather)

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

async def do_some_iterations():
    for i in range(10):
        print(datetime.now().time())
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('... Cool!')

async def do_something():
    print('something...')

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(
        do_some_iterations(),
        do_something()
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
    print("done")
```

This will print:

```
16:08:38.921879
something...
16:08:39.922565
16:08:40.923709
16:08:41.924823
16:08:42.926004
16:08:43.927044
16:08:44.927877
16:08:45.928724
16:08:46.929589
16:08:47.930453
... Cool!
done
```

You can also simply add another task:

```
async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(do_some_iterations())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(do_something())
```

In both cases the function needs to be awaitable.